# Kernel boot parameter reboot is not recognized

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, bootloader

I have added kernel command line parameter "reboot=acpi" in boot loader config file "isolinux.cfg". My boot loader config file looks like "DEFAULT linux vga=791 quiet reboot=acpi irqpoll initrd=/initrd rw root=/dev/ram0 loglevel=0". After booting verified the kernel command line parameters in /proc/cmdline and it is not showing "reboot=acpi" parameter. Output of /proc/cmdline is " BOOT_IMAGE=dev002:\EFI\BOOT\linux vga=791 quiet rw root=/dev/ram0 loglevel=0 pci=pcie_scan_all, realloc".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not booting using this isolinux default menu entry. You have irqpoll in that default menu entry you posted, but it does not appear in /proc/cmdline. And the pci=... which you see in /proc/cmdline does not show in the isolinux entry. Can you post the isolinux.cfg fully here /pastebin?